# Undo multiple file and folder 'git add'

Tags: git, git-add

I executed

```
git add .
```

and now I want to revert that git add. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: type this into a search engine "git revert add". Voila! http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`git reset` (which is equivalent to `git reset HEAD`) will un-`add` (more commonly "unstage") all files.

In Git, `revert` is used for undoing an existing commit (typically a commit that happened a while ago, or has been shared with others). If your commit has not yet been shared with others, there are ways to "rewrite" recent history such that you can pretend the changes you want to revert never happened in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

You can unstage all snapshots with `git reset HEAD` or selectively unstage paths with `git reset HEAD -- <filepath>`.