# running 'git rm' for a new file?

Tags: git, git-rm

I have done the following (in order to learn `git rm`).

Created an empty repository on an empty folder.
Created a file called test.txt, modify it and then run the following (with the consequent results).

```
git rm test.txt -> `fatal: pathspec 'test.txt' did not match any files`

git add test.txt && git rm test.txt -> 
error: 'test.txt' has changes staged in the index
                   (use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
```

So, my question is:

When would `git rm` test.txt be actually useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When would `git rm test.txt` be actually useful?

When you have already added *and* committed the file to your repository. [The docs tell us](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) that `git rm` is used to:

> Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index.

Comment: What's the difference between working tree and index? I have always heard working directory, staging area and git directory (repository).

Comment: Most of the time, if you haven't commited the file and you want to "undo" a `git add` then you will just use `git reset`. There is one exception, though: [`git rm --cached` is the only way to undo `git add` if your repository has no commits yet.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/682343/139010)

Comment: Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4084921 and http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/7_the_git_index.html

Comment: Well, if the index is my staging area, then ``git rm`` would remove the files from there, but instead (as in my original question) I get this when trying so: ``error: 'test.txt' has changes staged in the index``

Comment: It's just a warning. Did you not try `git rm -f text.txt`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But my question is still there. Why if git rm is supposed to remove files from my staging area, does not do it?

Comment: `git rm` does remove files from the staging area. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47282/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-matt-ball)