# How to ignore IDE settings on Git?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have below Git information and I would like to ignore settings of my IDE (Eclipse).

```
modified:   myproject/.classpath
modified:   myproject/.project
modified:   myproject/.settings/com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs
modified:   myproject/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
modified:   myproject/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
modified:   myproject/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
modified:   myproject/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
modified:   myproject/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs
```

I tried the below statements in my `.gitignore` file, but it doesn't work for these settings:

```
.project
.classpath
.settings
*.project
*.classpath
*.settings
/.project
/.classpath
/.settings
.project/
.classpath/
.settings/
*.project/
*.classpath/
*.settings/
```

I am using Mac OS X and I also added global gitignore file with these settings `git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'`, but I'm still getting the above Git update messages when I check with `git status`. What am I wrong?

Comment: Here is a book, you can refer to for any issue of git, if you didn't read yet: http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If those elements were already committed, you need to remove them first:

```
git rm --cached .project
git rm --cached .classpath
git rm --cached -r .settings
```

The `--cached` option allows them to stay in the working tree, while being recorded for deletion.
Once deleted, they will be ignored.

Once committed, the next changes will be ignored.

A simple `.gitignore` in `myproject/` folder is enough:

```
.project
.classpath
.settings/
```

Note the `/` for `.setting` folder: that will ignore everything in it.

Comment: Thanks for fast response sir ! I didn't already commit sir. When I change eclipse settings or some of my maven configurations , these messages were appeared and I always checkout (`git checkout`) line by line . That very worse things for me.

Comment: These files were not committed yet sir , if so how to do ?

Comment: @Cataclysm are they added to the index?

Comment: @Cataclysm did you try a `git rm --cached .project` anyway, just to see of the 'modified' status disappeared?

Comment: sir , please don't be mind . I am still a beginner on using Git. I really don't know what is **index**.

Comment: @Cataclysm I confirm: if you do a `git commit` now, the `.project` will then be ignored. If you do the other `git rm --cached` I suggested, and then commit, those other resources will be ignored.

Comment: sir now I didn't see them but I would like to know are they appear next time when I update settings ?

Comment: @Cataclysm once removed and committed, any future change to those file will be ognored because of your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: sir ! now I am confuse . my `.gitignore` file ? am I need to add in `.gitignore` file also ?

Comment: @Cataclysm yes, it is useful to add and commit the `.gitignore` file, as I mention in my edited answer.

Comment: If you add files (and not commit them), you have to remove them with git reset - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit .

Answer (score 2):

Following is my .gitignore config for a java web project:

```
*.class
*.swp
*.cache
*~

bin/**/*
target/**/*
build/**/*
gen/**/*

# tmp source folder
tmp/**/*


# js plugin
WebContent/js_plugin/lib/**/*
```

After git **1.8.2**, If you want to ignore a folder named **abc** in any folder or subfolder, use following:

```
**/abc/**/*
```

So, I suggest you upgrade your git, if it's too old.

By the way, in my opinion, if team is using the same IDE, you should sync the .classpath things to git, ofcause, this is base on you have convention to name your jdk / tomcat / ... things like this. So that,once a jar is added via maven, all people get it after pull.
But, if you commit eclipse config, when push, make sure that change is useful, if not, don't commit, e.g. 2 source folder just change their line orders, in this case you can git checkout -- xxx, to ignore that change, so that won't effect other people.

Comment: I use **git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)**

Comment: @Cataclysm What I propose will work with git 1.8.5.2

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me yeah but removing files from cache would be more helpful

`#IDE files .gradle .idea idea-module-files *.iml com.springsource.sts.config.flow.prefs org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.prefs`

org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.prefs
org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.prefs
.springBeans
eclipsebin
org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs

## NPM packages

**/node_modules

## Compiled class file

*.class

## Test classes

**/testclasses