# Get rid of files added to git that weren't committed and shouldn't have been added?

Tags: git

I made some changes to the code and pushed to a new branch.

Then I accidentally added a directory in another directory that is set to be ignored and committed an amendment to my last push.

This is not what I wanted to do. I actually meant to move the files to another directory then do the commit and push.

However, when I went to pull from master to get a clean copy, I found that all these files are now in conflict on my local machine. How do I remove them from git so there isn't this conflict?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo 'git add' before commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit)

Comment: Did you commit them or not?

Comment: @Martin I think I may have inadvertently committed as well.

Comment: Yep, everytime I do a hard reset, that dir is back when it is supposed to be ignored. If I check the repository on github, that dir is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove every un-tracked file doing

```
git clean -fxd
```

You could also do afterwards

```
git reset --hard
```

Doing both operations will restore your repo in a clean state. So you'll be able to pull again.

However, beware: it will actually deleted un-tracked files, and your un-commited local modification as well. Take a moment to ensure you might not loose important stuff.

---

Edit to take the comment into account: to put the repo in a clean state on the remote `master` branch, you can do

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: This seems to fix the problem, but then when I do a pull, I'm right back where I started.

Comment: Slight modification on what you suggest was to issue the commands `git fetch origin` then `git reset --hard origin/master` which resolved my issue.

Comment: Update your answer and I will accept and thanks for pointing me in the right direction!