# How to remove all added files in GIT

Tags: git

By mistake I used `git add .` so all files are added in staring area. I want to remove all those files from staring area.

I tried

```
git clean -fdx

git clean -df
```

but it isn't worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo 'git add' before commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit)

Comment: @Piyush do you only want to do it once? or do you want to ignore these files always? Also you have asked 2 questions in one, it is difficult for the community to find and answer, try asking a new question about adding only folders and not files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need use the `git reset --mixed`.
The `--mixed` if for clearing the stage/cache/index area.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do like this:

```
git reset . <-- will remove files from current index

git reset <filename> <-- for a specific file.
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is the case, then `git reset HEAD` will do the job