# Git error, need to remove large file

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error when I try to push to git and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
Counting objects: 1239, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1062/1062), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1239/1239), 26.49 MiB | 679.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1239 (delta 128), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: File log/development.log is 98.59 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: efd2d13efa4a231e3216dad097ec25d6
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File log/development.log is 108.86 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File log/development.log is 108.74 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File log/development.log is 108.56 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File log/development.log is 106.58 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File log/development.log is 103.70 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To git@github.com:myUsername/myRepo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myUsername/myRepo.git'
```

I'm guessing I need to remove the large file from the commit, but how do I do that?

Comment: Is this a rails project? Don't add your `log/` directory to git. That shouldn't be versioned.

Comment: I realize that now. Did not know that before.

Answer (score 56):

To remove large files, GitHub [suggests](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/):

```
$ git rm --cached giant_file
# Stage our giant file for removal, but leave it on disk

git commit --amend -CHEAD
# Amend the previous commit with your change
# Simply making a new commit won't work, as you need
# to remove the file from the unpushed history as well

git push
# Push our rewritten, smaller commit
```

Or if you want more [general information](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/) on how to work with large files on GitHub.

And next time add `/log` in your `.gitignore`

Comment: This doesn't work when you already made another commit deleting the file in an initial attempt to get past Git's annoyances..

Answer (score 36):

To improve upon one of the reply above, you need

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -f /path/to/file' HEAD --all
```

in order to remove your file even from the history. You need `-f` to force rewriting any backup and `--all` to remove file from all branches. More information here: [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Your large file error won't go away by removing it from the git cache because it is still lurking in the commit history.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! As a side note, I had to ensure to have forward slashes and relativ path for "/path/to/file"

Comment: how can I remove it from the commit history?

Comment: @jhabarsinghBhati That is exactly what the command does.

Comment: This works perfectly, but notice that git will throw a warning that users should try git-filter-repo instead.  See my answer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74174551/5741644

Comment: if you have made another commit after deleting the large file then this is the solution

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same issue recently, you can actually just filter the branch for specific file and remove it -

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD
```

Comment: You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.

Answer (score 19):

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

then exclude the file from the commit.

Note: Use HEAD~N to go back to N number of previous commits.

use this , go back a commit ,remove the large file from the commit if you can see it , then re commit and push.

this should solve the problem

Comment: Perfect solution. git reset --soft HEAD~n is the best command to go back

Answer (score 11):

I had already deleted the file thinking that would help. Running this command on the the branch worked for me.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/file'
```

Answer (score 8):

As of October 2022, git instructs the user to use 'git filter-repo' because:

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an 
alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
```

If (*for some reason*) the documentation for git-filter-repo (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) is not exactly clear, the following will definitely get you on track (it did for me, as I'm apparently a bit obtuse):

https://superuser.com/a/1589985/1054410

The following examples from the git-filter-repo docs show how to translate between, say:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -f /path/to/file' HEAD --all
```

to

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path /path/to/file
```

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#cheat-sheet-conversion-of-examples-from-the-filter-branch-manpage

Finally, you might need to add '--force' to the end of the statement, because git filter-repo expects a 'fresh clone'.

```
Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since      
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected freshly packed repo)
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed      
anyway, use --force.
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the previous answers:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_the_file/your_big_file'
```

Additionally, when I tried to pull I got "Refusing to merge unrelated histories".

Solution was to use:

```
git pull origin branch_name --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Then solve your possible conflicts, and push this time without the `big_file`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the previous answers:

We are going to remove the large file from the commit as you said

1. Do the push from the terminal just to get the large file path `git push --set-upstream origin Remote_branch_name`, locate the large file path in the errors, something like `RepositoryName/folders.../bigFileName`.
2. Remove the file from all the branches, `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path_and_big_file'` past the path that we found in section one instead of `path_and_big_file`.
3. Execute `git pull origin branch_name --allow-unrelated-histories` to not get `unrelated histories` error
4. Now try to push to git, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can revert git add before commit.

Check this question: [How to undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit)
It should work. And don't send big files to git, it's not worthy ;)

Also, exclude your logs, by adding git ignore on your logs path.

Comment: If you're getting this error it means you're trying to push which means you've already committed.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel

You can ignore that log(s) file from git repo using `.gitignore` file.
for that you have to add below line to your `.gitignore` file

```
/log
```

and try to commit again.
Hope this details help you to fix your issue.

Comment: I had already tried this and commited again but it did not work.

Comment: you need to revert git add, check my answer @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'file path'
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve mine with this

- git reset --soft HEAD~1
- git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
- git push -u origin master or git push