# How to push a large folder onto github, ignoring all files over 100MB?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have an enormously large folder. In this folder are a lot of videos and small files scattered around. I value the small files, not the videos.

I want to back up all the small files onto Github. If I directly try to upload the folder onto Github, I will get multiple large fille (>100 MB files) errors. The videos and small files are scattered around everywhere, making it difficult to remove videos one by one.

I know how to remove a single giant file from Github: [Git error, need to remove large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360043/git-error-need-to-remove-large-file/33363083#33363083)

However, is there an easy way to do this for *all* the large files in my folder, such that I can push everything else onto Github with ease?

Note: I don't want to use cloud storage, because all I want to store are my small files.

Comment: *I want to back up all the small files onto Github.* GitHub is **not** a backup solution.

Comment: To be sure we understand, you want to have only your small files in the repository? Large files will only live on your disk?

Comment: the best answer for it is over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain these large files locally, you first delete them from Git, but retain them in the working copy.

1. Find them all with `find . -size +100M -not -path './.git/*'`
2. Remove the files from Git, but keep the file itself: `git rm --cached`.
3. Add them to `.gitignore`.

You can combine steps 1 and 2: `find -X . -size +100M -not -path './.git/*' | xargs git rm --cached`.

I would recommend using this as an opportunity to move all your large assets to a single directory and ignore that directory.

Now that they're deleted from Git and safely ignored, use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to delete them from history.

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M --no-blob-protection my-repo.git
```

Comment: To clarify for #3 - how do I add them to .gitignore?

Comment: @GalenBlueTalon You can [append the output of the find command to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-a-text-file). If possible, first move those files to directories for large assets (like assets/videos/) and ignore just the directories.