# git and github - how do I reset the files to add in git add --all

Tags: git, github

I am receiving error message from github as follows;

```
root@staging:/var/www/example.com/app_dir# git push
Counting objects: 156, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
Writing objects: 100% (156/156), 148.29 MiB | 2.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 156 (delta 83), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (83/83), completed with 41 local objects.
remote: warning: File public/admin/json/lifts.geojson is 90.85 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: [snip]
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File writable/raw_data/runs.geojson is 783.31 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:[snip]/[snip]
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:[snip]/[snip]'
```

I have deleted the extra large files.  I have tried git reset, however, same error occurs. How can I redo the git add without the large files?

Comment: First of all, it's a warning, not an error :) See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363083/3842598

Comment: @Christian, I have already removed the large files.  There is no caching.  I still get the error.

Comment: I tried git reset but still same error.  I simply just wish to remove the files mentioned in git add.  No easy way?  If I could remove them I could redo, i could re-commit.

Comment: @VonC any easy way to do this please?