# How to remove file from git add index without locally deleting files from any repository

Tags: git

How to remove a file from the "git add " index if it has not yet been commited to the master branch.

I do not wish to actually delte the file itself ,just remove it from the index.
TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo 'git add' before commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git reset filepath
```

This will remove the file from add index and the changes will remain on your local system.

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to delete it form the index using this simply rrm command:

```
git rm --cached <file name>
```

If you will use

```
git rm <file>
```

it will remove it from both your file directory and your index, using the `--cache` flag will only remove it from your index.

Once you have removed the file you have to commit the change so use the `git commit --ammend` to modify the last commit.
It will remove the file from the last commit along side with all other changes which you have made.