# Is it possible to stage a file to its version in HEAD~1 without altering its contents on disk?

Tags: git

Imagine you have already staged and committed a number of changes but then decided that the changes ought to be separated into two commits. For newly created files, you can stage removing them from the commit without removing them from disk (with `git rm --cached filename`). Is there a similar command for modified files?

Essentially I would like to be able to stage the version of the file from the previous commit, and afterwards be able to re-run `git add -p filename` to select which changes belong in the first new commit vs the second. I don't want anything on-disk to change; my only goal is to split one commit into two with minimal work.

`git checkout HEAD~1 -- filename` stages what I want, but removes the changes from disk. I need them to stay on disk so I can proceed to add them to the next commit. (Note: You can undo this command with `git reset filename && git checkout filename`)

`git add HEAD~1 -- filename` feels like it should do what I want, but the command fails to run with `fatal: pathspec 'HEAD~1' did not match any files`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+add

Comment: `git reset HEAD~1 -- filename`

Comment: Interesting, I thought `reset` only operated on the current staging environment. I still wouldn't call this a duplicate of `git undo add` but nevertheless I appreciate the quick response! Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [phd noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851552/is-it-possible-to-stage-a-file-to-its-version-in-head1-without-altering-its-con#comment98364926_55851552), `git reset` can do this, because one of `git reset`'s many potential jobs is *copy a file from a commit to the index without touching the work-tree*.

It's a bit surprising because the *default* job of `git reset` *starts* by moving the current branch, as indicated by `HEAD`, to some new user-specified commit, and only *then* maybe—depending on `--soft` vs `--mixed` vs `--hard`—also copying files from the user-specified commit to the index, and then maybe on to the work-tree.  However, when `git reset` is used with path names, it changes tactics, dropping the *move current branch* job entirely.  That's why `git reset` does not allow `--hard`, `--soft`, or `--mixed` with path names.

When `git reset` is moving the current branch, if you—the user—don't specify some particular commit, the commit that `git reset` chooses is the one that the current branch names.  So this "move" from commit `$old` to commit `$new` is one where `$old` *is* `$new`, and there's no motion at all.  That's why `git reset --soft` with no arguments is a no-op, and why `git reset --mixed` or `git reset --hard` with no extra arguments does not change which commit is the current commit, but does reset the index and maybe also the work-tree.

Ultimately I always think that `git reset` packs too many actions into one user-facing command: it should be at least two, and probably more, separate user-facing commands, all of which might *run* `git reset` as their plumbing version of *how do we accomplish this user-goal-oriented operation*.  The `git checkout` command does this too, since it has several different user goals (*switch to new branch*, *get one specific file from one specific commit without switching branches*, and so on).