# How to remove a certain type of files and directories from git add before commit?

Tags: linux, git

I added few directories and files by using  `git add` , some of which I don't want in repository.

I would like to remove all the directories and files which either start with `.` or end with extension `yml`.

How can I achieve this?
I do not want to undo all the adds but only few adds.

Comment: you can add those extension in addingnore file : ignored - a file which Git has been explicitly told to ignore.

Comment: Thing is I have already added those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-do-i-undo-git-add-before-commit)

Comment: I do not want to undo all the adds

Comment: Have you commited the addition?, i.e, have you run `git commit` after `git add`?

Answer (score 2):

IF you have not committed yet, you can remove from the index any file you need with [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) or [`git rm --cached`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached) if you really want to not track them, which is the case here:

```
git rm --cached -- .*
git rm --cached -- *.yml
```