# Discard changes in the preparation area to take them to the working directory

Tags: git, reset, checkout, staging

Add by chance all the directories of my computer with git add, I would like to discard them all, and try with git reset and checkout -. 
I am currently in the master branch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-do-i-undo-git-add-before-commit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+%22git+add%22

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `git reset file-to-discard` to remove `file-to-discard`
>   from "changes to be committed".
>
> Or use `git reset` to remove all changes.

`git checkout -` will simply return you to previous branch. It's not suitable for your case.