# How do I un-stage ALL files staged for commit?

Tags: git, github

say I wanted to un-stage all these files. Is there a single command to do so?

```
hend0825@csel-apollo:/home/hend0825/3081_s20/repo-hend0825/project/src $ git add -A
hend0825@csel-apollo:/home/hend0825/3081_s20/repo-hend0825/project/src $ git status                                                                                                                                                          On branch pause/resume
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/pause/resume'.
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
modified:   ../../exercises/ex02_inheritance/composed.h
modified:   ../../exercises/ex02_inheritance/derived.h
new file:   ../../exercises/ex02_inheritance/inherit
new file:   ../../exercises/ex02_inheritance/inherit.h
modified:   ../../exercises/ex02_inheritance/main.cc
new file:   ../../exercises/ex02_inheritance/main.o
modified:   ../drivers/bus_driver.cc
modified:   ../drivers/route_driver.cc
new file:   #bus.cc#
modified:   bus.cc
modified:   bus.h
new file:   ../tests/.gitignore
new file:   ../tests/.route_UT.cc.swp
new file:   ../tests/bus_UT.cc~
new file:   ../tests/route_UT.cc~
modified:   ../web_code/web/main.cpp
modified:   ../web_code/web/my_web_server_command.cc
modified:   ../web_code/web/my_web_server_command.h
modified:   ../web_code/web/visualization_simulator.cc
modified:   ../web_code/web/visualization_simulator.h
modified:   ../web_graphics/sketch.js
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-do-i-undo-git-add-before-commit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+unstage+all+files

Answer (score 0):

`<file>` is optional:

```
 git reset HEAD
```

Comment: I tried that:hend0825@csel-apollo:/home/hend0825/3081_s20/repo-hend0825/project/src $ git reset Head                                                                                                                                                      fatal: ambiguous argument 'Head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: it's `HEAD`, not `Head`. All caps

Comment: See [What is HEAD in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git)

Comment: I see thanks. Is there a way to get rid of the untracked files? so if I add all, only the changes not staged for commit would be added?

Comment: `git commit -a`

Comment: or `git add -u`