# Undo GIT Stage and get local changes back

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-for-windows, git-stage

I have done a GIT Stage from Visual Studio accidentally. There are some files which I don't want to commit. Therefore I want to undo my Stage action and get my local changes back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-do-i-undo-git-add-before-commit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse action is

```
git reset -- path/to/file
```

It'll unstage this file **but actual changes in the file are kept**, they now appear as "unstaged changes".

You can also add multiple paths separated by spaces

```
git reset -- path/to/file some/other/path/*
```

The nuclear option (unstage everything) being the very concise :

```
git reset
```

---

**Some examples from the doc :**
To reset a single file, [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-Resetasinglefileintheindex).
To reset multiple files, [there](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-Undoadd) (although for this one you don't need their step (4) which is very specific to the context).

Comment: What if I want to unstage all the files in the solution? there are about 100 files which got staged and I don't even remember some paths.

Comment: @KasunG Good question, I should have mentioned it, you're right. Edited.

Comment: @KasunG As a sidenote, if you ever need to have the list of everything that's already staged, use `git diff --staged --name-only`. If we didn't have the nuclear option above, we could as well do the same like this `git reset -- $(git diff --staged --name-only)`