How do you remove a file from a pull request (not rm the file)?
Say I have a file in a pull request and the diff looks something like this:
file1.yml
1     - goodbye world
    1 + hello world

I want the file to simply say "goodbye world"
I tried "git rm --cached file1.yml" and now the diff looks like this:
file1.yml
1     - goodbye world

...which is not what I want. I want the file not to appear in the pull request as it isn't relevant to that branch, not remove the file entirely. Also, copying and pasting isn't an option since I don't know what the file on main is supposed to look like (it might be changed by someone.)

git reset <file>; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-do-i-undo-git-add-before-commit

technically what you are asking about is not a "pull request" (not a Git thing, a Git hosting -- e.g. GitHub -- thing) -- you're asking about the Git "staging area." FWIW

@DavidP.Caldwell After I do this I do a "git add " but when I try to do a git commit it says "nothing to commit, working tree clean" and when I try to push it says "Everything up-to-date" but the file1.yml is still being changed in my pull request on github.

The pull request on GitHub represents the state of the branch at the time you last pushed the branch to GitHub. git add and git reset affect your local staging area (not even your local branch!). So there's some stuff to disentangle. You might need to add a bunch more detail to your question about the state of GitHub, state of your local, and so forth to make it possible to figure out how to do what you want.

If it's a public repo, you could just link to it; if not, we might need to know the state of the local branch, state of origin/[local], what the output of git status is, etc.

My guess is you need to go back to the original version by doing a git checkout version-with-goodbye-world -- file1.yml and then a commit and push -f ("force") to reset the file's contents on your PR, then git checkout version-with-hello-world -- file1.yml to get your working copy back to the state you're in now. But it's hard to tell.

A pull request in GitHub will display any differences between the source and destination branches. If you push a commit that makes file1.yml identical in both branches, then the PR won't show that file any more.
I can think of two ways to do this off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are more (and some might be better).

Edit the file manually until they match. (This is only a good option if the changes are very small, like in your hello world/goodbye world example.)
Assuming that you're in the PR's source branch, and that main is the destination branch, and that the latest commit to main has the "good" version of the file, git checkout main -- file1.yml will check out the version of file1.yml from the main branch (and only that file). Once that's done, git add file1.yml, commit, and push.


This is close... and probably will work for most scenarios... but, if the file was changed in the target branch after your current branch diverged, then you will get those changes in your PR.... you need to get it from the commit where the branches diverged... probably something like git checkout $( git merge-base @ main ) file1.yml .

That's a good point, thanks! I'll edit my answer to mention that the second option is only useful if main has the "good" version.
